# How do I manage a Non-default Django database

Tags: django, postgresql

I am having trouble using my non-default database in my Django (v1.8) app. When I
try makemigrations and migrate the PostgreSQL database does not get updated.

Here is my Django structure:

```
fbrDjangoSite
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- fbrDjangoSite
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- requirements.txt
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- wsgi.py
|-- fbrPostHasteAppV0_1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- migrations
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- router.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- views.py
```

## fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from fbrPostHasteAppV0_1.models import MusicianTable   # gvim ../fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/models.py +/MusicianTable
from fbrPostHasteAppV0_1.models import AlbumTable      # gvim ../fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/models.py +/AlbumTable

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(MusicianTable)
admin.site.register(AlbumTable)
```

## fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Define your models/tables here.
class MusicianTable(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True

class AlbumTable(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(MusicianTable)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
```

## fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/router.py

```
class fbrPostHasteAppV0_1Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return False
        return None
```

## fbrDjangoSite/settings.py

```
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1',             # v ../fbrPostHasteAppV0_1/__init__.py
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    # ...
    'fbrPostHasteDb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'myhost.us.overlord.com',
        'PORT': '0000',
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['fbrPostHasteAppV0_1.router.fbrPostHasteAppV0_1Router',]
```

Here is the output when I run the migration commands:

```
[fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py] /<3>django/fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py/fbrDjangoSite> python manage.py makemigrations fbrPostHasteAppV0_1 --verbosity 3
    /fobar-tools/pylibs/lib/python/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py:1497: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Router.allow_syncdb has been deprecated and will stop working in Django 1.9. Rename the method to allow_migrate.
      if not router.allow_migrate(db, cls):
    Did you rename the fbrPostHasteAppV0_1.Musician model to MusicianTable? [y/N] y
    Migrations for 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
      0002_auto_20150408_1653.py:
        - Create model AlbumTable
        - Rename model Musician to MusicianTable
        - Remove field artist from album
        - Delete model Album
        - Add field artist to albumtable
[fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py] /<3>django/fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py/fbrDjangoSite> python manage.py migrate --verbosity 3 
    /fobar-tools/pylibs/lib/python/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py:1497: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Router.allow_syncdb has been deprecated and will stop working in Django 1.9. Rename the method to allow_migrate.
      if not router.allow_migrate(db, cls):
    Operations to perform:
      Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages
      Apply all migrations: fbrSimDataV0_2, sessions, admin, polls, auth, contenttypes, fbrPostHasteAppV0_1
    Synchronizing apps without migrations:
    /fobar-tools/pylibs/lib/python/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py:336: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Router.allow_syncdb has been deprecated and will stop working in Django 1.9. Rename the method to allow_migrate.
      return [model for model in models if self.allow_migrate(db, model)]
      Creating tables...
      Installing custom SQL...
      Installing indexes...
    Running migrations:
      Applying fbrPostHasteAppV0_1.0002_auto_20150408_1653.../fobar-tools/pylibs/lib/python/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/operations/base.py:107: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Router.allow_syncdb has been deprecated and will stop working in Django 1.9. Rename the method to allow_migrate.
      router.allow_migrate(connection_alias, model) and
     OK
    /fobar-tools/pylibs/lib/python/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py:70: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Router.allow_syncdb has been deprecated and will stop working in Django 1.9. Rename the method to allow_migrate.
      if not router.allow_migrate(using, Permission):
    The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:
        fbrPostHasteAppV0_1 | album
        fbrPostHasteAppV0_1 | musician
```

But when I look at the dtatbase the "table" has not been added.

```
[fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py] /<3>django/fbrDjangoServerV0_1.venv.py/fbrDjangoSite>       psql -h localhost -p 0000 --command "\l" postgres
                                 List of databases
       Name    |  Owner   | Encoding  | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges
    -----------+----------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
     postgres  | myuser   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     |
     template0 | myuser   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/myuser          +
               |          |           |         |       | myuser=CTc/myuser
     template1 | myuser   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     | =c/myuser          +
               |          |           |         |       | myuser=CTc/myuser
     test      | myuser   | SQL_ASCII | C       | C     |
    (4 rows)
```

I was under the impression that Django could create the table and keep it in
sync whenever I made changes to the model. Is my understanding correct and if
so what am I doing wrong here?

## UPDATE

One of my issues is that my router code was based on and older version of
Django. I am not sure if this is exactly correct now but it closely resembles
the documentation now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

```
class fbrPostHasteAppV0_1Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return db == 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None
```

The other issue is that I was not calling migrate with --database:

```
 python manage.py migrate --database=fbrPostHasteDb
```

But now I am getting another error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "fbrPostHasteDbV0_1" does not exist
```

Continuing to figure out what else I messed up...

## UPDATE 2

So I created the database like this:

```
psql -h localhost -p 8080 --command "CREATE DATABASE fbrPostHasteDbV0_1"
```

But it created fbrposthastedbv0_1 instead.

So Once I changed all the references and the names I was able to:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=fbrPostHasteDb
```

Comment: $ ./manage.py migrate --database=fbrPostHasteDb, can I get your debug? It may be that changing certain fields in postgres also requires you to do so manually, I had to change a varchar field to text field a month ago and saw that migrations weren't affecting the column, so I was forced to do so manually.

Comment: Its up there. A little hard to see, second code snippet from the bottom about 1/3 down the snippet. What I am showing here is an ALTER but I did not have the table in psql originally so I expected it to do a CREATE but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my issues is that my router code was based on and older version of
Django. I am not sure if this is exactly correct now but it closely resembles
the documentation now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

```
class fbrPostHasteAppV0_1Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'fbrPostHasteAppV0_1':
            return db == 'fbrPostHasteDbV0_1'
        return None
```

The other issue is that I was not calling migrate with --database:

```
 python manage.py migrate --database=fbrPostHasteDb
```

But now I am getting another error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "fbrPostHasteDbV0_1" does not exist
```

Continuing to figure out what else I messed up...

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to manually change the necessary fields, I'm not sure of the exact postgres bugs but I dealt with a similar situation a month ago.  Migrations are a pain at times, but after fixing them report to:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/

Comment: Well that kinda stinks. I choose postgres specifically because it seem to be the best supported by Django to do the migrations for me... I wonder if I should just use MySQL instead.

Comment: So far it seems like this is a multi-db "confusing documentation" and user error problem and nothing to do with postgreSQL issue.